# Python 2.6 in mac corrupted because of failled update

Tags: python, macos, python-2.6

I'm a mac newbie and I tried to update my python version from 2.6 to 2.7. Unsuccessful, I changed my mind and uninstalled the python2.7 I had. I had a previous issue that if I typed something like:

```
python setup.py install
```

It would not install the package for python2.6, installing to the removed 2.7 version instead, to make it work I have to put

```
python2.6 setup.py install
```

And now when I try to install something with easy_install or pip (by the way, pip I have installed after 2.7 issue) I got the following huge message errors: [here](http://pastie.org/1789045) and [here](http://pastie.org/1789165). I want to know how can I clean up my mess.

Comment: I'm not sure about cleaning up the existing mess, but [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) gives you a nicely-packaged DMG install for getting a clean copy of Python onto your system.

Comment: That ActivePython will give me a version of 2.7 python, which is great, but how do I uninstall that in case thats not what I need?

Comment: How did you update Python to 2.7?

Comment: Yes, now I get a different message: http://pastie.org/1789288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were trying to install MySQLdb, how about you give [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) a try?

1. Install ActivePython 2.7 (*it [co-exists](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/faq.html#does-activepython-collide-with-other-python-distributions-on-mac-os-x) with Apple's System Python 2.6*)
2. Open Terminal and type `pypm install mysql-python` (*see [PyPM Index](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/mysql-python/)*) .. no compilation required

Make sure that `/usr/local/bin/` is in front of your `$PATH`.

To [uninstall](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/installnotes.html#osxpkg_uninstall) ActivePython, you can do:

```
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Scripts/uninstall
```

Or, use `sudo pythonselect 2.6` to switch the default Python in `/usr/local/bin` (if you have multiple versions of non-System Pythons installed)